# android spinner custom rows

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have a `Spinner` and a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.
For odd/even rows on this spinner i set some color, background, font size.
Also in my cursor there is a empty value. For this i want to display just a 5 pixels height line. I do not know how to do this.

Like a example i want something like this

```
   Row1
   Row2
   Row3
   ----
   Row4
   Row5
```

Here is my attempt code

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.dropdown_selector_odd);
} else {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.dropdown_selector_even);
}
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_name);
String driverSpinnerRow = text.getText().toString();
if (driverSpinnerRow.trim().length() == 0) {
    // Here must add this line
    text.setHeight(5);
}
return view;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you see with the code that you have here?  Does it not toggle between the odd and even layouts?  Or do you see nothing at all?  If you post more code I am sure that we can help you.

Comment: So instead of text, you want a solid, 5-pixel height line? Just want to make sure I understand correctly, because you're setting the `TextView` height which is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is what you need](http://android-er.blogspot.com.ar/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html). Instead of **images**, suppose that are **lines**, and instead of setting the **source** of the image, set **visible/invisible** to the lines.

[Here is a similar tutorial](http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/03/using-custom-layouts-for-spinner-or-listview-entries-in-android/) about how to create a custom layout for the rows. Add the 5 pixels height line to the row layout and set it to be invisible. Then in the adapter set it to visible when needed.
[This ListView tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) may help to create a custom adapter.